# Piecing Together Parts Needed for Multivariable Chain Rule

Tags: multivariable-calculus, word-problem, chain-rule

**The Question**

You want to estimate the rate at which the temperature (degrees F) in a
concert hall changes per hour, dT/dt, based upon how many people are in the room, *p*, and the total heat output of equipment in the room, measured in kilowatts, ℎ. At a given moment, people are flooding into the concert hall at a rate of 100 people per hour and electronics are consuming 500 kW each hour. It is estimated that the temperature in the room should increase by 0.1 degrees F per person and that the temperature rises by 1.2 degrees per kW of energy. Estimate dT/dt and explain precisely what it means. So far I've gathered that we have:

**My Issue**

So right off the bat, I am pretty sure I will need to use the chain rule to calculate dT/dt, the issue for me is isolating the necessary information from the text. So basically I'd like to know what each part of the chain rule (shown below) is in relation to this word problem.

$\frac{dT}{dt} = \frac{∂T}{∂x}\frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{∂T}{∂y}\frac{dy}{dt}  $

Comment: What quantities are varying in the problem?  That will tell you what the variables are.

Comment: @saulspatz so y = .1p and x = 1.2h?

Comment: Actually, now that I read the problem closely, I'm not sure what it means.  It says the temperature rises $1.2$ degrees F per kW, but that $500$ kW are being consumed.  Does this make $600$ degrees?  That doesn't make any sense.  For the other part, if the temperature rises $.1$ degree per person, and there are $100$ people entering the hall per hour, the increase in temperature due to the people is $100(.01)=1$ degree per hour.